# Are checkboxes slower to load than switches?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, checkbox

I have an `Activity` with 34 `Switch`, and loading the activity is fine.

However, when I try to replace the `Switch` with `CheckBox` the activity takes a full second to load.

Is this a general problem with `CheckBox` or is my code just not appropriate?

My code for the activity, simplified (shows only 1 `CheckBox`)

```java
public class Myactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckBox MyCheckbox1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);

        MyCheckbox1 = findViewById(R.id.mycheck1);
        Mycheckbox1.OnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                if(((CompoundButton) view).isChecked()){
                    //do something
                }else{
                    //do something else
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My XML code for the Checkboxes:

```xml
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/mycheck1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Option1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating 52 switches or Checkboxes in XML is going to put the load on UI Rendering. You should use RecyclerView to reuse the view so it will take very less time to render.